# Links redirecting to localhost after migration to server

Tags: links

I developed a website on my localhost and migrated it to my web server. The site displays mostly everything on the home page (I lost some font settings as far as I can tell) and all the content seems to be intact as well as the menu items. But all links, images and nav items redirect to my localhost site. Even when I try to log into my wp-admin it accepts the credentials but redirects me to the admin for my localhost site. Is this my permalinks all messed up or something else? I have tried:

- searching for an .htaccess file but there is none
- defining a home & siteURL in the wp-config file (this just breaks the layout of the site although it still is active)
- edited wp-options table to be new URL for 'siteURL' but couldn't see a row for 'home'

**RESOLVED**

I found the 'home' field. And that proved to be the clincher. So if anyone comes across this same issue, I resolved it by editing both the 'home' and 'siteURL' fields in the wp-options table of the database on the server (not the localhost one) to replace the 'localhost/sitename' with 'http://www.sitename'. Both 'home' and 'siteurl' should be the same. That did the trick and all my links now work.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicate domain database to local - How?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141149/duplicate-domain-database-to-local-how)

Answer (score 5):

if anyone comes across with this issue, I resolved it by editing both the 'home' and 'siteURL' fields in the wp-options table of the database on the server (not the localhost one) to replace the 'localhost/wordpress' with 'http://www.youehostedsitename'. replace Both 'home' and 'siteurl'.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-write your answer in the answer field so that people see this thread as answered. Did many research and finally found a thing that works.

RESOLVED

I found the 'home' field. And that proved to be the clincher. So if anyone comes across this same issue, I resolved it by editing both the 'home' and 'siteURL' fields in the wp-options table of the database on the server (not the localhost one) to replace the 'localhost/sitename' with 'http://www.sitename'. Both 'home' and 'siteurl' should be the same. That did the trick and all my links now work.

Comment: You could wait to gain 10 reputation points and then add this as a comment. This is not really an answer.

Comment: Now you can comment; the answer is this like vonnie answered by him/her self in the question instead posting independent.